# Getting 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist' while launching Chrome Browser using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist' while launching Chrome Browser using Selenium
I have listed below versions for testing

**Chrome Version: 97.0.4692.71
Chrome driver version: 97.0.4692.71
Selenium Version : 3.10.0**

Exception:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 97.0.4692.71 (adefa7837d02a07a604c1e6eff0b3a09422ab88d-refs/branch-heads/4692@{#1247}) on port 18242
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Tests run: 4, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 61.603 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
beforeClass(icom.test.Login)  Time elapsed: 61.519 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
System info: host: 'PU2L6718', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00B1FDC3+2555331]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AB77F1+2127857]
    Ordinal0 [0x009B2E08+1060360]
    Ordinal0 [0x009D0DC2+1183170]
    Ordinal0 [0x009CD605+1168901]
    Ordinal0 [0x009CAFC1+1159105]
    Ordinal0 [0x009FC22F+1360431]
    Ordinal0 [0x009FBE9A+1359514]
    Ordinal0 [0x009F7976+1341814]
    Ordinal0 [0x009D36B6+1193654]
    Ordinal0 [0x009D4546+1197382]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00CB9622+1619522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D6882C+2336844]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BB23E1+541697]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BB1443+537699]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ABD18E+2150798]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AC1518+2168088]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AC1660+2168416]
    Ordinal0 [0x00ACB330+2208560]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x750A6359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x778787A4+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77878774+180]

    at icom.test.Login.beforeClass(Login.java:30)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)